# AttributeError: module 'skopt' has no attribute 'plots' error message

Tags: python, import

I think it's quite interesting enough to ask.

Version is `skopt==0.8.1` and in my folder "C:/Users/myname/anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/skopt", there are many `.py` files, such as `__init__.py`, `acquisition.py`, `callbacks.py`, `plots.py`, `utils.py` and so on.

I can import `skopt.utils`, `skopt.acquisition` and so on, but especially not `skopt.plots`.

With an error message `AttributeError: module 'skopt' has no attribute 'plots'`

Any advices?

```
>>> import skopt
>>> skopt.plots
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'skopt' has no attribute 'plots'
>>> skopt.utils
<module 'skopt.utils' from 'C:\\Users\\myname\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\skopt\\utils.py'>
```

Comment: Show us the import code and the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I did. And I tried `import skopt.plots` in the jupyter `.ipynb` file and it worked, but it still doesn't in the cmd. What's going on??